# Two @POST on a single resource

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

Using Jetty with Jersey embedded.

I was wondering if it is possible for one of my resources to have 2 method with `@POST` annotation on the same path but use the parameters to distinguish which method to call.

For example, lets say I have `/api/v1/MyResource`. And the MyResource class look like this:

```
// The /api is set in my context.
@Path("/v1/MyResource")
public class MyResource {
    private final MyService service;

    public MyResource(MyService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response doPost(MyParam param){
        this.service.doStuffWith(param);
    }

    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response doPost(MyParamOfADiffType param){
        this.service.doStuffWith(param);
    }
}
```

Since my service has two implementation of the `doStuffWith()` function, I expected Jersey to try to serialize the request body into a `MyParam` object and if its not working try into a `MyParamOfADiffType` object. Then if its not working I expected a 500 Internal error.

But I get a ModelValidationException instead. Anyone know if what I am trying is possible?

Comment: as I know routes are put in a `map`where the key is the route path, and the value is the method that will be invoked when requesting this `url`, since it's a `map`you can't map a route more than once

Comment: @mustabelMo Ah... this is a bit irritating. I guess I'll have to change my design.

Comment: I guess you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754650/versioning-rest-service-by-creating-abstract-class) it may help you

Comment: @mustabelMo The thing is, it is not so much of a second version. its more I have 2 valid and useful ways to doStuffWith that could be applied to the same resource.